# Problem with copy rotation of bone

Tags: rigging, bone.constraints

I am having problems rigging this character. I want the hand and finger bone to rotate with the hand IK bone. At this stage it rotates in different axis' and I can't seem to get it to work properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Gi3n5_Huo-kjSNJf449t7GRK1YvtKc1z/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Hello, what does it give if you parent (in Edit mode) the bone called hand.L to the bone called hand_IK.L, does it give the desired result?

Comment: Thank you! It worked